# In Dart do we have method similar to range method in python?

Tags: dart

In `python` we can write the below code to a generate list of numbers

```
for num in range(10):
    print(num)
```

or

```
print(list(range(0, 10))
```

Can we generate range of numbers similarly in `Dart` this would make programming more efficient in `Dart`?

Comment: Yes, see this equestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798397/create-a-list-from-0-to-n

Comment: Amani thanks for sharing the link can we generate number from -100 to 100 using `var list = List<int>.generate(10, (i) => i + 1);` the generate method?

Comment: @Amani seems in the like which you provided seems there are package is we install we can get the range functionality but looks like its not build into dart